# Redusing resolution from a cad model

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, rospackage, voxel-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a ros package to reduce the resolution of any cad model (.stl/.dae/.obj)?
I am looking for something like [this](http://drububu.com/miscellaneous/voxelizer/?out=obj), where any cad model can be converted into a lower resolution voxel grid

I need this lower resolution model (of obstacles) to perform collision checks during path planning. Since its highly computationally expensive to do the same of the original model

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286344/redusing-resolution-from-a-cad-model/) by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 272 on 2018-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A ROS package for this could be [convex_decomposition](http://wiki.ros.org/convex_decomposition). This was (is?) used by the PR2 description package. It doesn't actually resample your geometry using voxels, but creates multiple convex hulls that together represent and encompass the original mesh completely.

Two things to note about this package: 1) it's deprecated (see [this](https://github.com/ros/convex_decomposition/issues/6) issue) and 2) I haven't used it, so can't comment on whether it (still) works.

I mentioned it because you specifically ask for a "ros package".

---

For some packages in ROS-Industrial we've been using [gaschler/bounding-mesh](https://github.com/gaschler/bounding-mesh) for a similar purpose, and it returns quite nice results for our use-cases. It is not a ROS package though.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-23**:
I typically use Blender's *decimate* modifier when I really need to subsample. If I just need a convex hull, Meshlab has a good filter for that.

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2018-03-23**:
@gvdhoorn thanks a lot for your answer and detailed description. And I specifically asked for a ros package since Im working in ros. Are there any other c++ libraries or something similar which can be used to do this? (other than the one you have already mentioned)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-23**:
I'm not entirely sure I understand why this has to be a ROS package: working with meshes seems to me to be a completely independent subject / task. It does not make much sense to me to try and force that into a ROS pkg.

Can you clarify what making it a ROS pkg would improve?

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2018-03-23**:
yes I understand your point. And I am already convinced that using a ros package for this is not necessary.